# Display error and information messages to front-end users in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

My aim is to display error and information messages to front-end users in WordPress.

In BuddyPress, `bp_core_add_message()` can be used to add a feedback (error/success) message to the WP cookie so it can be displayed after the page reloads. Is there a function like this available in WordPress?

Ref:
https://github.com/buddypress/BuddyPress/blob/master/bp-core/bp-core-functions.php#L902

**Update**

Adapted from bp-core-functions.php:

```
function add_message( $message, $type = '' ) {

    // success is the default
    if ( empty( $type ) )
        $type = 'success';

    // Send the values to the cookie for page reload display
    @setcookie( 'wp-message',      $message, time() + 60 * 60 * 24, COOKIEPATH );
    @setcookie( 'wp-message-type', $type,    time() + 60 * 60 * 24, COOKIEPATH );

}


function setup_message() {

    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['wp-message'] ) )
        $template_message = stripslashes( $_COOKIE['wp-message'] );

    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['wp-message-type'] ) )
        $template_message_type = stripslashes( $_COOKIE['wp-message-type'] );

    add_action( 'template_notices', 'render_message' );

    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['wp-message'] ) )
        @setcookie( 'wp-message', false, time() - 1000, COOKIEPATH );
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['wp-message-type'] ) )
        @setcookie( 'wp-message-type', false, time() - 1000, COOKIEPATH );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'setup_message', 5 );


function render_message() {

    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['wp-message'] ) ) {
    $template_message = stripslashes( $_COOKIE['wp-message'] );

    if ( ! empty( $template_message ) ) :
        $type    = ( 'success' == stripslashes( $_COOKIE['wp-message-type'] ) ) ? 'updated' : 'error';
        $content = apply_filters( 'render_message_content', stripslashes( $_COOKIE['wp-message'] ), $type ); ?>

        <div id="message" class="template-message <?php echo $type; ?>">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
        </div>

    <?php
        do_action( 'render_message' );
    endif;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just guessing - Have you tried adding do_action( 'template_notices' ); to your WP templates?

Comment: Hi @shanebp - yeah, got the hook in my footer.php. If you look in that function (I linked to on GitHub for easiness), the message is sent to the $bp global. e.g. `$bp->template_message = $message;` - is it 100% necessary to do that? or could I just set the cookie?

Comment: You can always set the cookie, but the question is how to read it. It's not clear what you're trying to do ( or why!), but maybe you need a custom action in WP that calls a function that harnesses $bp global.

Comment: I'm working on a site that doesn't use BuddyPress but would like to emulate the way BP sets and displays _template notices_. The code that does that is in bp-core-functions.php. The code uses both the $bp global and cookies. The problem is, the $bp global isn't available in my WP-only install.

Comment: So I was wondering - _must I_ send the info or error message text to a global variable (like BP does with the $bp global) or can I just use cookies?

Comment: Lots of WP plugins use custom messaging on the front end. You can use a global or a cookie. A global is easier.

Comment: I'm actually finding the cookie approach easier. My cookie approach is working actually but seems to require a page refresh in order to check if a cookie has been set e.g `if ( isset( $_COOKIE['wp-message'] ) )` - How would I achieve this sort of thing using globals?

Comment: @shanebp see my update above. I have a cookie solution working. Be good to have your thoughts?